# Tensorflow low GPU utilization with high memory used

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, gpu

I have an RTX 2060 GPU with i7-9750H, but whenever I try to run Tensorflow(v 2.1) code, my GPU utilization is around 0%, whereas GPU memory consumed is around 4.9GB/6GB, every time. I tried with different model sizes as well along with using allow_growth = True, to make sure TensorFlow doesn't allocate complete GPU memory initially, but the same thing is happening. What am I doing wrong? (For example, I am running MIT deep-learning course lab3 entire solution code with 0% GPU utilization.)

Comment: Profile the code and see where is the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, additionally allow_growth did not work with TF2.1 (not exactly sure why). Instead, I used tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(GPU, True) and that brought down the memory usage. It turns out, the code did not require as much of GPU. I tried running ConvNets and then the utilization picked up. Thanks!